# How to add default code snippets to blogdown posts?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, blogdown

I've set up [my blog](https://data-se.netlify.com/) using blogdown.

Now I would like to define some standard code snippets that should be included in each post (e.g., for centering images). Take this R-code as an example; it should be included automatically in each post:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  out.width = "70%",
  fig.align = 'center'  
)
```

I've read the section on templates in the [blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html), but I could only find html based templates, which appears not so straightforward to me.

How can I add R-code snippets per default to posts using blogdown?

Comment: Maybe `blogdown` has the same `before_chapter_script` option as `bookdown`, because if this is the case then it's what you want.

Comment: That's a good idea, and it was what I hoped, but it did not work. I tried to put  `before_chapter_script = "_common.R"` in `config.toml` on the root level and in the same file under `[params]`. But it seemed not to reckognize this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `.Rprofile`, as explained in [Section 1.4 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html). The easiest way is probably to use an RStudio project, and create a `.Rprofile` file in the root directory of the website project, in which you set the **knitr** global chunk options.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something, but I could not get it working. I've put `knitr::opts_chunk$set(...)` to `.Rprofile` in the project root folder. But these options apear to not being reckognized.

Comment: Now it worked - the UNevaluated chunk with the global knitr options needed to taken out of the post, as it obviously overwrote the .Rprofile settings. Thanks!